# Is it possible to verify empty input from the user in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm writing a spring boot application and I'm having some troubles in verifying empty input from the user.
Is there a way to validate an empty input from the user?
For example:

```
@PostMapping("/new_post/{id}")
public int addNewPost(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody Post post) {
    return postService.addNewPost(id, post);
}`
```

Here I want to add a new post only if the user exists in the database but when I send this post request I am getting the regular 404 error message and I am not able to provide my own exception although in my code I validate if the id equals to null.

http://localhost:8080/new_post/

Any idea what can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you posting a localhost URL? Why don't you verify if the post content is empty before posting it to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/new_post/{id}", "/new_post"})
public int addNewPost(@PathVariable(required = false, name="id") Integer id, @RequestBody Post post) {
    return postService.addNewPost(id, post);
}
```

But the ideal way to handle this is using `@RequestParam`. `@RequestParam` is meant exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do it like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/new_post/", "/new_post/{id}"})
public int addNewPost(@PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) Integer id, @RequestBody Post post) {
```

This way you are also handling the URL when ID is null

Answer (score 0):

***I Think This is a Better Answer for Two Others :***

```
@PostMapping("/new_post/{id}")
public int addNewPost(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody Post post)
{
    if(!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(post))
    {
       return postService.addNewPost(id, post);
    }
    else 
     return null; // You can throws an Exception or any others response
}
```

**id :** Not required to check 'id', because with out id the requested method is not call.